# return user model with eager loading laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
 return $data =InteractiveSession::with('messages.user')->where('exercise_id',$exercise->id)->first();
```

This code will return data like below

```
{
"id": 1,
"exercise_id": 48,
"messages": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "from_user": 69,
        "message": "Hi",
        "interactive_session_id": 1,
        "user": {
            "id": 69,
            "first_name": "Jobin"
        }
    }
]}
```

how can i return data like below??

```
{
"id": 1,
"exercise_id": 48,
"messages": [
    {
     "id": 1,
      "from_user":{
       "id": 69,
       "first_name": "Jobin"
        },
        "message": "Hi",
        "interactive_session_id": 1, 
    }
]}
```

i have  tables interactivesession,message,users, using hasmany relation

Comment: why? you can access data the Laravel way, $data->messages->first()->user->first_name

Comment: Don't ever do that if you know you are going to need that information, and more care if you are in a loop... [Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) is the WHY not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a relation for `from_user` to the user model, and then do `return $data = InteractiveSession::with(['messages.user', 'fromUser'])->where('exercise_id',$exercise->id)->first();` (remember `fromUser` should be your relation name)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$data = InteractiveSession::with('messages.user')->where('exercise_id',$exercise->id)->first();

$data->transform(function($record) {
    $messages = $record->messages->transform(function($message) {
        'id' => $message->id, 
        'from_user' => [
            'id' => $message->user->id,
            'first_name' => $message->user->first_name
        ],
        'message' => $message->message,
        'interactive_session_id' => $message->interactive_session_id
    });

    return [
        'id' => $record->id,
        'exercise_id' => $record->exercise_id,
        'messages' => $messages
    ];
});
```

Comment: This seems to be more difficult and more code ,, is any other way?

Comment: @helloworld You can use loop, but the code will be longer. I think this is the shortest you can do considering you are using Eloquent with eager loading.